# how to create java generic method which returns String or ArrayList<String>

Tags: java, generics

As a part of self-improvement, I'm practising generics in java, and I have a case - It's just a learning case - not a real-world scenario...
I'm trying to write a generic method which takes a string as an argument and based on return type it should return either String or List.

In the normal (easy logic) situation I've done like that:

```java
public class ConfigFile{

    String fileName;

    public ConfigFile(String filename) {
        this.fileName = filename;
    }

    public String getFilename() {
        return fileName;
    }

    public String readFileAndReturnString() {
        String content = "";
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(this.fileName)));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                content = content.concat(line + "\n");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("== IO exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;

    }

    public ArrayList<String> readFileAndReturnStringArr(String filename) {
        List<String> content = new ArrayList<>();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(this.fileName)));
            String line;

            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                content.add(line);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("== IO exception");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return content;
    }
}
```

I can test them easily:

```java
...
@Test
public void printStringTest() {
    String someStrFile = configFile.readFileAndReturnString();  
    System.out.println(String.format("==== str: %s", someStrFile));
}
    
@Test
public void printArrayTest() {
    ArrayList<String> someArrFile = configFile.readFileAndReturnStringArr();
    for (String line : someArrFile) {
        System.out.println(String.format("arr: %s", line));
    }
}
...
```

Now i would like to make a generic method which would merge logic from both of methods and i'can't figure out how can I achieve this (if it's even possible)

```java
    public <T> T readTheFile() {
   //     ...implementation
    }
```

to use it like this:

```java
ConfigFile someConfFile = new ConfigFile("C:\\temp\\someFile.txt");
String strConfFile = someConfFile.readTheFile(); //to return here String
ArrayList<String> arrConfFile = someConfFile.readTheFile(); //to return here ArrayList<String>
```

I've tried few things but I failed.
Can you please help me figure out that? Or maybe there is some other solution for such case or maybe it totally doesn't make sense

Thanks in advance

Comment: What needs to be generic about a method with a fixed parameter and fixed return type?

Comment: the purpose of "printStringTest" method is not good because test cases must work automatically not by human as you did with log that and see what does its output

Comment: your approach is like that you are using selenium test that instead of click on a button with code log a message to attend tester that you must click on X button then you must see a color of an element will be changed

Comment: probably not...but as i wrote - it's just a part of my own exercise and test is not the main point :) The main thing which i want to focus is a generic method which can return either String or ArrayList<String>. I'm not digging deeper if it makes sense or not - it's just an exercise on java generics

Comment: You should close the `BufferedReader` after reading the file.

Answer (score 2):

You don't really have to use generics, but simply extract the common code you have into another method (adapted the code slighty to use modern idioms):

```
public void readFileInto(Consumer<? super String> accumulator) {
    try(BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(this.fileName)))) {
        
        String line;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            accumulator.accept(line);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new UncheckedIOException(e);
    }
}
```

Which the two other methods then can delegate to:

```
public String readFileAndReturnString() {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    readFileInto(sb::append);
    return sb.toString();
}

public ArrayList<String> readFileAndReturnStringArr(String filename) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    readFileInto(list::add);
    return list;
}
```

If you are not wise in the arts of lambdas and method references which look like this:

- `foo -> bar(foo)`
- `this::bar`
- `Baz::bar`

Then I suggest reading the following article: [Lambda expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html)

Comment: Thanks for pointing out about extraction common method. Surely it's a good solution. But here I just want to know if it's possible - if yes - then make it generic. I know that we should simplify things and maybe using generics, in that case, won't bring good effect...But this time it's a case like: "You won't do that...No? Hold my beer..."

Answer (score 2):

You should use standard library API in [java.nio.Files](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk14/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) like this.

```
public String readFileAndReturnString() throws IOException {
    return Files.readString(Paths.get(this.fileName));
}

public List<String> readFileAndReturnStringArr() throws IOException {
    return Files.readAllLines(Paths.get(this.fileName));
}
```

It's a bad design to return an empty string or empty list when an `IOException` is thrown. Because you cannot distinguish from reading an empty file. You should explicitly throw back the `IOException`.

Comment: `java.nio` is just such a handy package

Comment: Thumbs up, but just in case...[java.nio.file.Files.readString()](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html#readString(java.nio.file.Path)) is available from >jdk11
p.s. i'm still on jdk8, but readAllLines() is doing the stuff